# It is not possible to move a window using ActiveWindow.Left

Tags: excel, vba, macos

With Office 365 (up to date) for Mac, trying to execute

```
ActiveWindow.Left = ActiveWindow.Left + 100
```

doesn't produce the expected result. The window moves horizontally of course but also vertically and that is unexpected.

Did someone find a solution to solve the problem ?

Comment: Hi. i've tested and its ok. it must be other thing changing the movement. maybe an onchange envent ?

Comment: Are you using Windows ?. Because that works under windows 10 but not under macOS.

Comment: yes, i didnt realize it was a mac... sorry